# Matlab: Error using load Unable to read MAT-file. Not a binary MAT-file. Try load -ASCII to read as text

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab file, `A.mat`, saved in a Dropbox folder in my mac (**macOS Monterey version 12.5.1**). I open Matlab (**R2022a**), go to this folder, and run `load('A.mat')`. I get the following error:

```
Error using load
Unable to read MAT-file /Users/.../Dropbox/Folder/A.mat. Not
a binary MAT-file. Try load -ASCII to read as text.
```

When I try the same command in another computer of mine, it works perfectly. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall Matlab and get the same error. I think it may be related to the fact that the file is in a "cloud" (Dropbox) but I don't understand how to fix the problem. Any help?

Same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866400/unable-to-read-mat-file-not-a-binary-mat-file-try-load-ascii-to-read-as-text) but I could not understand the solution.

Comment: Did you find [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/705578-why-do-i-get-error-using-load-cannot-read-file-when-trying-to-load-a-mat-file-on-a-differen) ?

Comment: How was the file created? Have you compared checksums and file lengths to verify that the file was not corrupted during transfer?